# Can I disable PHP within a Laravel (Blade) view file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, template-engine

I was to understand that MVC templating was used as a means of locking down a view from using any substantial programming logic. Testing the Blade system for Laravel 4, I notice that I am still able to include PHP content into the view.

Can I disable PHP in a Blade template? Essentially turning the file into a .html file with some additional possibilities (eg, Blade looping and sections/includes).

Comment: Blade files are just compiled to PHP files anyway.

Comment: Thanks Jason (coincidentally I found your blog/tuts minutes after seeing your reply in an unrelated Laravel search). I thought templating prevented PHP (useful for designers working on the frontend of a project), but I must be mistaken.

Comment: If you did manage to “disable” PHP, then your variables, loops etc wouldn’t get parsed. If you want to restrict any “logic” to a template language then you might want to take a look at something like Twig or Mustache.

Answer (score 0):

If you need programming logic in your views you're probably doing something wrong. Try to do the logic in your controller and inject the variables into your views.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, this is exactly why I don't want PHP to be available in the view. I thought using Blade would prevent this, but I can see that it is still possible. (The PHP logic I including was only to test to see if it would allow it).

Answer (score 0):

Blade templates compile to php, so you won't be able to eliminate php altogether.

There is something you can work around your project by creating your own compiler, or extending Blade's.

You will need to work your own solution out on how to handle rendering the parts in php that are used in your template, I would just render them as is, for example:
- if someone forgot an `<?php echo $example; ?>` that's what the engine would render.